# Lavarel - Error in relation: Call to undefined relationship [nota] on model [App\Nota]

Tags: php, laravel, model, relation

I want to make the following query with Eloquent:

```
$nota=DB::table('notas')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'notas.id_user')
        ->select('notas.id','notas.nombre', 'notas.descripcion', 'users.name AS user_name', 'users.email')
        ->first();
```

I try to make the relation in the models and called like this, in my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{

    $nota = Nota::with(['user','nota'])->first();
    print_r($nota);

    return view("notas.detalle", compact("nota"));
}
```

But i get the follow error:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException
>   Call to undefined relationship [nota] on model [App\Nota].

My models looks like this:
Nota.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nota extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function notas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Nota');
    }    
}
```

Comment: there is no nota in your model change it to notas. beside this code might not stop because both models are related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your understanding of relationship. You don't make any relationship named `nota` but you are using it and ridiculously with the same model. So firstly make the relationship right using [naming convention](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

In `Nota` model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id_user');
    }
```

In `User` model

```
public function notas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Nota','id_user');
    }
```

And now in controller

```
$nota = Nota::with('user')->first();

return view("notas.detalle", compact("nota"));
```

Look this is an eager loading. You can lazy load the relationship too.

In view now you can access object property like

```
{{ $nota->nombre }}
```

And relationship object like

```
{{ $nota->user->email }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this function `Nota::with(['user','nota'])->first()`

Why do you want nota with nota. it's sounds ridiculous isn't it?

So just remove it, then everything will work fine.

```php
$nota = Nota::with(['user'])->first();

return view("notas.detalle", compact("nota"));
```

Comment: Fine, works. But i want to get the users.email field. And the result dont get that.

Comment: It can't be, You can access email of the user by `$nota->user->email`